# No se puede pasar StringVar a str

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo que meter el nombre en un caja y luego ese nombre meterlo a una cadena. Después según que Checkbutton este activado me añada un texto. El nombre es una StringVar y luego al añadirlo a la cadena no me deja y no se como solucionarlo. Agradecería que me ayudarais

```
from tkinter import *   
def nombrar():
    nombre.set(nombre1.get())


def seleccionar():
    cadena = ""
    cadena += nombre

    if (novia.get()):
        cadena += "Con novia"

nombre1 = StringVar()
nombre = StringVar()



Label(root, text="Nombre del protagonista").pack()
Entry(root, justify="center", textvariable=nombre1).pack()
Button(root, text="Elegir el nombre", command=nombrar).pack(side="left")
Label(root, justify="center", textvariable=nombre).pack()
```

El error que me da es este
        cadena += nombre
    TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "StringVar") to str

Comment: prueba con cadena += nombre.get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para concatenar StringVar a un String, primero, necesitas obtener su valor String.

Esto ya lo tenías hecho en otro paso distinto arriba de tu error, en:

```
def nombrar():
    nombre.set(nombre1.get())
```

Por lo cual, tan solo debes reproducir los mismos pasos:

```
def seleccionar():
    cadena = ""
    cadena += nombre.get()
```